# Get value of <td> in Java - request.getParameter

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

Im trying to get the values of some td elements where the data consist of data from MySQL table. It displays the data fine in my browser (e.g. if i change type from "hidden" to "submit"), but when I try to get the value i only get null.

Here are my jsp and it displays the correct results in the browser.

```
<td>
    <form action="history.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="res" value="<%=his.getRes()%>"/>
    </form>
</td>
```

When i try to print the values however, I only get "null" at of evey :

```
<% 
String res = request.getParameter("res");

System.out.print(res);
%>
```

I'm still very new, so it's proberly a straight forward answer. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Are the code snippets from two different jsp files? I looks like the second one is the history.jsp which will be loaded when you submit your form in the in the first snippet. Is that correct?

Comment: All the code are in the same jsp file. The file is history.jsp.

Comment: if you want to retrieve values from within the same page, use javascript. the input parameter doesn't exist in the request until you submit your form

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you change the name of your variable :

```
String newname = request.getParameter("res");

System.out.println(newname)
```

Comment: In some version of tomcat, some variable names generated an error, I`m just suggesting in case.

Answer (score 0):

- One can submit (=send) only one `<form>`. So one must assume there is just one single `td` with one `<form>`. Forms also may not be nested in an outer form.
- It need some way to submit the form.

So experiment first with:

```
<td>
    <form action="history.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="res" value="<%=his.getRes()%>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
</td>
```

This will show whether `his.getRes()` yielded something. And allows a manual submit in the browser.